# jquery select all tags inside a html table cell

Tags: jquery, html

My HTML table contains a set of tags (anchor, plain text,line break etc) inside each cell.

Now my question is i need to get all the contents of the table cell into an array, like if the cell contains anchor and plaint text i need both into an array. In this way i need to get a number of arrays (equal to the number of cells)

i tried this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      var row = 4;
      var items = [];
        $('#test tr:eq(' + row + ') td').each(function(colindex, col) {            
          //alert(t);
          items.push(t);

      });
      alert(items.toString());
 });
```

but this is giving me all the cells into an array where as i need each cell to give me an arrray.

can any one please help me out here.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.children()`.

`$('element selector').children()`

See http://api.jquery.com/children/

Comment: hi rudi, i used the above method but in vain... all i need to do is to iterate through each tag with in the table cell and get the tag and push it into an array, may be can you post a sample code.

Comment: This works fine: `$('element selector').children().each(function() { items.push(this); });`